# Is there a fix for too many open files error in Gridgain cluster?

Tags: gridgain

Gridgain cluster failed with error "too many open files". I have set ulimit values as recommended by GridGain. i.e nofile --> 65536.

Even after increasing nofile to 65536, cluster is crashing. Is there anything to check or configure?

````
[15:29:12,957][SEVERE][nio-acceptor-client-listener-#80][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to accept remote connection (will wait for 2000ms).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to accept connection: GridWorker [name=nio-acceptor-client-listener, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1651073352943, hashCode=804329932, interrupted=false, runner=nio-acceptor-client-listener-#80]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.accept(GridNioServer.java:3081)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:3002)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:421)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:249)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.processSelectedKeys(GridNioServer.java:3131)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.accept(GridNioServer.java:3060)
    ... 3 more
    ```
````

Comment: It depends on how many caches and nodes you have. How large is your numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two possibilities here.

1. The number of file descriptors did not increase. It can be set at multiple levels (the system, your user) and if you do it in the wrong place it won't have any effect. You don't say how you did it, so I'll just point you to this article: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/
2. If you have a small number of nodes and a large number of caches/tables, you may need more than 2^16 file descriptors. If this is the case, you'll need to increase the limit further

Comment: We are still facing issues related to "too many open files". 
We have set the limit to 100k.

```
/etc/security/limits.conf 

ignite soft nofile 100000
ignite hard nofile 100000


cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
100000
```

The number of open files increasing day by day and hitting the max limit and node is crashing.

Here is the growth of open files on the node.

Day1 - 150k
Day2 - 350k
Day3- 600k
Day4- 850k
Day5- Ignite Node crashed!!

I have set client connection IdleTimeout=180 second and no luck.
Looks like some resource is leaking.
Is there anyway to check?

Comment: How many caches and nodes do you have? What is the configuration of the caches? Are they partitioned or replicated?

Comment: Number of caches: 45, 
Number of nodes: 3, 
Cache Mode : PARTITIONED, 
CPU : 4, 
RAM : 60 GB on each node, 

Cache Configuration: There is no individual cache settings made in XML configuration file.

However, below parameter is set while creating the cache.
  backups=3

Comment: You've got more backups than nodes, so it's effectively replicated. For 45 tables, that adds up to about 50,000 open files per node. The rest can't be explained given the information you've provided.

Comment: Please let me know the information that you need to figure out the root cause of "Too Many open files" issues.

Comment: Unless you're constantly creating new caches, there is no reason for the number of required file descriptors to keep increasing. I'm not aware of any bugs here in Ignite.